# Checking Multiple Row Custom Validator in Angular 4 Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a very simple problem which I can't get it. First, I have an ingredient which has an approved quantity. And that ingredient has several expiration dates. However, I want to check if my expiration dates which has the "quantity to transfer" is not more than the approved quantity.

How should I check this? I already finished some parts BUT this one I couldn't compare since it has to check several rows of "quantity to transfer" against the one approved quantity. Here's the code link below:

[FORKED LINK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-f5aozw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image: EXAMPLE]

```
customValidator(group: any) {
    if ((group.controls.transfer_qty.value > group.parent.parent.controls.approved_qty.value)) {
      return { out1: true }
    }
    if ((group.controls.transfer_qty.value > group.controls.available_qty.value)) {
      return { out2: true }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: It will take some time , :)

Comment: Its bit complicated , as you want 2 validations on group of inputs

Answer (score -1):

I usually implement custom form controls when nested forms are involved.
A good rule is to abstract out code into small pieces, in our case break out your angular code into small components.

You can implement custom form controls using [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)

I modified your example to show what I mean:
[Modified Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-ksjfpt?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

[Example without implementing ControlValueAccessor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-bjrpe5?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Your code works exactly as my code. My problem is when the approved quantity is 100. and it has two expiration dates, you input 100 in the first quantity to transfer and 2 in the second. It should output an error. This is my problem

Comment: tried the scenario you are talking about, works as expected, can you check again, I made a change recently

Comment: Is the link the same?

Comment: The problem is still the same. Can you check at my edited question. I have attached the picture.

Comment: In my picture, i inputted 100 and 1. It should output an error since it is more the approved quantity of 100

Comment: Oh, correct me if I am wrong, so the sum of quantities entered should not exceed the approved quantity?

Comment: Yes. btw your code is a bit long. Can you edit my code?

Comment: The error message you gave when it is more than the approved quantity is wrong. When i type 100 and 1 in the input field

Comment: modified your example - link above in answer, hope that helps

Comment: I mean, can you not change the structure of my code. Just add something but do not change anything

Comment: I mean, can you not change the structure of my code. Just add something but do not change anything

Comment: First u accepted it as the answer, now you downvote, all the best , I tried to help

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Someone else did downvote you